# How can I prevent my Winston logger from printing multiple times in the database?

Tags: javascript, logging, winston

Winston Logger Print multiple time in database

> output link is in last

I created file with Winston logger first comment section is for i have to print in files which i don't and another comment is while i am checking there is still code which i didn't show because its commented it describe HTTP, debug and silly

```
const logger = createLogger({
    format: format.combine(format.timestamp(), format.json()),
    transports: [
        // new transports.File({
        //     filename: './info.log',level:'info'
        // }),
        new MongoDB({
            level: 'error',
            db: db.MONGODB_URI,
            collection: 'logger'
        }),
        // new MongoDB({
        //     level: 'warn',
        //     db: db.MONGODB_URI,
        //     collection: 'logger'
        // }),
        new MongoDB({
            level: 'info',
            db: db.MONGODB_URI,
            collection: 'logger'
        }),
```

There is my config file which i think works fines because it generates output

```
const constants = require('../config/constants');
const { logger } = require('../config/logger');
let _ = require('lodash');

const logGenrate = (WEB_STATUS_CODE) => {
    try {
        if (constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.OK === WEB_STATUS_CODE || constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.CREATED === WEB_STATUS_CODE || constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.NO_CONTENT ===WEB_STATUS_CODE) {
            logger.info(`Status code ${WEB_STATUS_CODE}`);
        } else if (constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.BAD_REQUEST === WEB_STATUS_CODE || constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.UNAUTHORIZED === WEB_STATUS_CODE || constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.NOT_FOUND === WEB_STATUS_CODE) {
            logger.error(`Status code ${WEB_STATUS_CODE}`);
        } else if (constants.WEB_STATUS_CODE.SERVER_ERROR === WEB_STATUS_CODE) {
            logger.error(`Status code ${WEB_STATUS_CODE}`);
        }

    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log('Error(logGenrate)can not connect with files', err);
    };
}
```

here status code describe for multiple codes which i use in this program

```
    WEB_STATUS_CODE: {
        OK: 200,
        CREATED: 201,
        NO_CONTENT: 204,
        BAD_REQUEST: 400,
        UNAUTHORIZED: 401,
        NOT_FOUND: 404,
        SERVER_ERROR: 500
    }

End : this output is when i run api with bad request it generates two logs in Database and when i use info it print 3 times and if i use silly or http it prints multiple time 

now i know there is level 
err - 0,
warn - 1,
info - 2

i think when info is logging it got all the data about warn and error but when i comment all the thing and only generate error which is level 0 it should be print only one time why its print two times


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ib9U0.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftaKO.png
```